# I can't use the new version on google cloud (app engine) without clearing cookies

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

I have a React application that is running on google cloud (I am new to google cloud). My react version is "react": "16.8.3" (I think it is irrelevant but anyway).

My problem is that when I have some developments I am running npm run build again and then I am using this command 'gc app deploy' to deploy the new version. After this when I run 'gc app browse' I can see and use my new version of app but when I go to real url I see it as the previous version. After I clear my cookies on browser (I have the same problem with the other browsers also) I can use the new version.

I am using cloudflare and all the configurations that I made as following this article; https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/deploying-react-app-to-google-app-engine-a6ea0d5af132 did not do any further configurations. I am using AWS for some other project and don't have this problem. Is there anyone with similar issue or anybody to help?

Btw, my app.yaml as below;

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 10
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build
```

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not splitting traffic but I'd try setting the `Cache-Control`, `Expires` or `Vary: Cookie` headers suggested in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/splitting-traffic#avoiding_caching_issues) and see if that changes anything.